# CSS Problems in IOS9 and Safari 9

Tags: css, safari, ios9

I am having problems with a website since iOS9 and Safari 9 came out. It seeme like the CSS does not work properly. Additionally, the menu does not work on mobile devices, so maybe there is a problem with js too...

You can find the page under http://ueli-blaser.de. The site is running on wordpress and there are a lot of people using this template and having this problem. Unfortunately the author of it does not respond.

Does anyone have an idea, what causes those problems?